# Get the value of a field in a Lotus Notes Form

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

I need help, I need to know how can I get the value of a field of a form 
I know how to get the field name but not the value in it...
Here's a trunked version of my code:
By the way, the loop make no sense for now but it will be used properly once I found how to get the fields values,...
Thank you all!!

```vb
Forall field In form.Fields     
    fieldCount = fieldCount + 1
    msgString = msgString & Chr(10) &   "     " & field

    If (field  Like "*Act*")  Then          
        ActfieldCount = ActfieldCount + 1

        If (field  Like "RNomAct1")  Then
            Msgbox("RNomAct1 found in SourceString!")
'thoses do not work             

'               test = field.GetItemValue("RNomAct1")   
'               test = field.FieldGetText("RNomAct1")   
'               Messagebox( test( 0 ) )

        End If
    Else
        Msgbox("Could not find the SearchString.")
    End If

End Forall
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere you should have a reference to a document. Or if you don't you can access the current document via some other objects:

```
Dim ws as New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim uidoc as NotesUIDocument
Set uidoc = ws.CurrentDocument
```

Then you can get the field value with this call:

```
uidoc.FieldGetText("name-of-field-here")
```

Comment: Thank's I got it with some search too, sory  I am realy new in Lotus Notes (and very confuse with the notion of Documents UIDoc and so on....)